# Move another window and rebound if touch borders of desktop

Tags: javascript, html, windows, visual-studio, create-react-app

I have a question.
How can I create a program that moves a specific window, for example discord around the desktop and if it touches an edge it bounces?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) is the function you are looking for.